# Mudar um class que está dentro de um id com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Preciso mudar a palavra ASSINANTE que está na DIV `id="nav_menu-5"` dentro do `H3`
por SERVIÇOS.

```html
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div id="nav_menu-3" class="widget widget_nav_menu">
    <h3 class="widgettitle title m_title m_title_ext text-custom">Parceiros</h3>
    <div class="menu-rodape_parceiros-container">
      <ul id="menu-rodape_parceiros" class="menu">
        <li id="menu-item-162" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-162"><a href="https://redesfiepa.org.br/novo/parceiros/#eluid9bd491ff">Empresas Mantenedoras</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-163" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-163"><a href="https://redesfiepa.org.br/novo/parceiros/#eluidcc9d7ccc">Empresas Apoiadoras</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-164" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-164"><a href="https://redesfiepa.org.br/novo/parceiros/#eluid903a0340">Empresas Cooperadoras</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="nav_menu-5" class="widget widget_nav_menu">
    <h3 class="widgettitle title m_title m_title_ext text-custom">Assinante</h3>
    <div class="menu-rodape_assinante-container">
      <ul id="menu-rodape_assinante" class="menu">
        <li id="menu-item-168" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-168"><a href="#">Serviços às Indústrias</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-169" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-169"><a href="#">Serviços a Fornecedores</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
let menu = document.getElementById("nav_menu-5");

menu.innerHTML="<h3 class='widgettitle title m_title m_title_ext text-custom'>SERVIÇOS</h3><div class="menu-rodape_assinante-container"><ul id="menu-rodape_assinante" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-168" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-168"><a href="#">Serviços às Indústrias</a></li> <li id="menu-item-169" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-169"><a href="#">Serviços a Fornecedores</a></li> </ul></div>";
```

Comment: o qual a sua dívida?  o que tentou fazer? mostre seu código `javascript`

Comment: Para facilitar a leitura, coloque o código na pergunta.

Comment: Você usa jQuery?

Comment: Não tinha usado nesse projeto mas posso usar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem muitas formas de fazer isso. Além da forma mostrada pelo Victor Carnaval, pode usar também o `querySelector()`, que aceita seletores CSS e é bem mais simples e flexível:

```js
document.querySelector("#nav_menu-5 h3").textContent = "Serviços";
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div id="nav_menu-3" class="widget widget_nav_menu">
    <h3 class="widgettitle title m_title m_title_ext text-custom">Parceiros</h3>
    <div class="menu-rodape_parceiros-container">
      <ul id="menu-rodape_parceiros" class="menu">
        <li id="menu-item-162" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-162"><a href="https://redesfiepa.org.br/novo/parceiros/#eluid9bd491ff">Empresas Mantenedoras</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-163" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-163"><a href="https://redesfiepa.org.br/novo/parceiros/#eluidcc9d7ccc">Empresas Apoiadoras</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-164" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-164"><a href="https://redesfiepa.org.br/novo/parceiros/#eluid903a0340">Empresas Cooperadoras</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="nav_menu-5" class="widget widget_nav_menu">
    <h3 class="widgettitle title m_title m_title_ext text-custom">Assinante</h3>
    <div class="menu-rodape_assinante-container">
      <ul id="menu-rodape_assinante" class="menu">
        <li id="menu-item-168" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-168"><a href="#">Serviços às Indústrias</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-169" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-169"><a href="#">Serviços a Fornecedores</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Como você quer alterar o conteúdo texto do elemento `h3`, você pode usar um método do próprio objeto `document` para buscar qualquer elemento HTML dentro da div selecionada ("nav_menu-5"). Como o texto está no primeiro elemento `h3` - suponhamos que podem existir mais de um - utilizamos o índice `[0]` para selecioná-lo.

```js
let menu = document.getElementById("nav_menu-5");
let h3 = menu.getElementsByTagName("h3")[0];

h3.innerHTML = "Serviços";
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div id="nav_menu-3" class="widget widget_nav_menu">
    <h3 class="widgettitle title m_title m_title_ext text-custom">Parceiros</h3>
    <div class="menu-rodape_parceiros-container">
      <ul id="menu-rodape_parceiros" class="menu">
        <li id="menu-item-162" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-162"><a href="https://redesfiepa.org.br/novo/parceiros/#eluid9bd491ff">Empresas Mantenedoras</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-163" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-163"><a href="https://redesfiepa.org.br/novo/parceiros/#eluidcc9d7ccc">Empresas Apoiadoras</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-164" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-164"><a href="https://redesfiepa.org.br/novo/parceiros/#eluid903a0340">Empresas Cooperadoras</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="nav_menu-5" class="widget widget_nav_menu">
    <h3 class="widgettitle title m_title m_title_ext text-custom">Assinante</h3>
    <div class="menu-rodape_assinante-container">
      <ul id="menu-rodape_assinante" class="menu">
        <li id="menu-item-168" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-168"><a href="#">Serviços às Indústrias</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-169" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-169"><a href="#">Serviços a Fornecedores</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```